# Node server is not able to render react app child pages

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I wanted to render react pages using node server but somehow besides the index react page,no child pages are getting rendered.

**My Project structure**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmPB1.png)

**My Server index.js with PORT=3001**

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require("path");

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")));

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Express + TypeScript Server");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**Added the proxy to my react-app package.json**

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
```

**React Routes**

```
 <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Authenticate />} />
            <Route path="webrtc" element={<WebRTCDemo />} />
            <Route path="login/callback" element={<LWACallback />} />

            {/* Using path="*"" means "match anything", so this route
                acts like a catch-all for URLs that we don't have explicit
                routes for. */}
            <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
```

**Node server is able to render Index route but any sub routes are not working.**

```
http://localhost:3001/webrtc is not rendering. any ideas ?
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsOVS.png)

- Deleting the build folder and npm folder and rebuilding again does not solves the issue.

Comment: Don't post code as images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this route below your /api route.

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'../client/build/index.html'), 
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Are you sure ? I thought this `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")));`  should do that already

Comment: I tired any what you mentioned but it throws error `{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"stat","path":"/../project/enterprise-console/server/client/build/index.html","expose":false,"statusCode":404,"status":404}`

Comment: it looks path issue you can use the updated code. It resolve the path issue.